# How to retain changed button text in android?

Tags: android

In my project I have one edit text and one button.
When the project loads and I press the button,
the text of the button changes to the value of edit text.
But when I press the back button the change of button text does not persist.

I have included the snapshot which can describe my problem better.

I basically want the button text change to persist.

Please help.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: It really will really not retain the value. You need to store the text somewhere then reuse it

Comment: Where is the snapshot and code?

Answer (score 1):

The text doesn't show up on reopening the app because it was stored temporarily and when you closed your app it got destroyed. To retain the text you can store it in shared preference or file and on app startup load the text of the button from that source and if source is not present(When opening app for the first time) then put the default text on the button.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity onCreate () method, you can add this code:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String btnText = preferences.getString("btnText", "");
if(!btnText.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    yourButton.setText(btnText);
}

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                  editor.putString("btnText",yourTextEdit.getText().toString());
                  editor.apply();

                  ....your code
          }
       });
```

In your layout xml file, set your button default text. `android:text="@string/yourtext"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the text somewhere and load it when the activity starts. There are various ways to do this but I think [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) will work for you.

In the on click function for the button set the Shared Preference and in the Activity's `onCreate` check if the same Shared Preference is set. If the value is present load it else load the default value.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the button for first time after getting text from edit text use the following code to save the edit text text that to be set on button in shared prefrences:
In on Button Click method:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(....);
String text = et.getTex().toString();
```

then you set it on button and so..

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("buttonText", text);
 editor.commit();
```

then when you relauch the app in onCreate method use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String value= prefs.getString("buttonText", ""); 
button.setText(value); //whatever you button is
```